# How to find all unnamed modules

Tags: docker

I got docker compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'elasticsearch:7.9.1'
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    volumes: 
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/elastic_search_volume:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
```

When I run:

`docker volume ls`

I see no results. How to list unnamed volumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker volume ls` as you've shown it will list all of the volumes that exist.

However, in the `docker-compose.yml` file you show, you're not creating a named or anonymous volume.  Instead, you're creating a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to connect a host directory to the container filesystem space.  These aren't considered "volumes" in a technical Docker sense, and a `docker volume` command won't show or manipulate those.

Reaching directly into `/var/lib/docker` usually isn't a best practice.  It's better to ask Docker Compose to manage the named volume for you:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    volumes: 
      # No absolute host path, just the volume name
      - elastic_search_volume:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
volumes:
  elastic_search_volume:
    # Without this line, Compose will create the volume for you.
    # With this line, Compose expects it to already exist; you may
    # need to manually `docker volume create elastic_search_volume`.
    # external: true
```